# Validate CSV file in a web application C#

Tags: c#

I am uploading a CSV file through a web application to a data table.
Simple example would be 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 was just wondering what would be the best way to validate that its a CSV file before trying to upload it
for example the following code works on a txt file or a image

```
           string CSVFilePath =   Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
           string ReadCSV = File.ReadAllText(CSVFilePath);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765492/how-to-validate-csv-in-c

Comment: You can use "<input id="model" type="file" accept="csv" name="model" data-val="true" data-val-required="File is required" /> " it will take only csv files.

Comment: can you explain this in more detail please