# Using LINQ to search comma separated string

Tags: entity-framework, linq, csv

There are a number of records in the table, and there is a column called AssignedTo, and the value for AssignedTo is comma separated string, the possible values for it could be something like:

```
"1"
"2"
"3"
"11"
"12"
"1,2"
"1,3"
"2,3"
"1,2,3"
"1,3,11"
"1,3,12"
```

If I use the following LINQ query to search, in case value = 1

```
 records = records.Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Contains(value) || search == null);
```

It returns the records with AssignedTo value

```
"1", "11", "12", "1,2", "1,3", "1,2,3", "1,3,11", "1,3,12"
```

I really want to only return the records with AssignedTo containing "1",
which are "1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,2,3", "1,3,11", "1,3,12", do not want "11" and "12"

If I use the following LINQ query to search the qualified records, still value = 1

```
records = records.Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Contains("," + value + ",") ||  
                        x.AssignedTo.StartsWith(value + ",") ||  
                        x.AssignedTo.EndsWith("," + value) || 
                        value == null);
```

It returns the records with AssignedTo value "1,2", "1,3", "1,2,3", "1,3,11", "1,3,12", but missing the record with AssignedTo value "1".

Comment: Can you split each assignedto column into a list of integers before the LINQ? Then your code should work.

Comment: I tried that, However I have var records = db.BudgetProjects.AsQueryable();, after that if I write something like string[] ids = AssignedTo.Split(',');, it has error that AssignedTo does not exist in the current context

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367621/entity-framework-query-a-comma-separated-field/35368849#35368849

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since something like this is likely a search filter, doing the operation in-memory likely isn't a very good option unless the row count is guaranteed to be manageable. Ideally something like this should be re-factored to use a proper relational structure rather than a comma-delimited string.

However, the example you had was mostly there, just missing an Equals option to catch the value by itself. I'd also take the 'value == null' check out of the Linq expression into a conditional as to whether to add the WHERE clause. The difference is with the condition in the Linq, this will generate that into the SQL, where-as by pre-checking you can avoid the SQL conditions all-together if there is no value specified.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    records = records.Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Contains("," + value + ",") ||  
                    x.AssignedTo.StartsWith(value + ",") ||  
                    x.AssignedTo.EndsWith("," + value) || 
                    x.AssignedTo == value);
```

This would catch "n,...", "...,n,...", "...,n", and "n".

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve Py! It seems this is working very well!

Answer (score 2):

A better method would be to split the string and search the results:

```
records = records.Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Split(',').Contains(value) || search == null);
```

Note that you can't use this method directly in an EF query since there's no way to translate it to standard SQL. So you may want to filter using your `Contains` as a starting spot (to reduce the number of false positives) and then filter in-memory:

```
records = records.Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Contains(value) || search == null)
                 .AsEnumerable()  // do subsequent filtering in-memory
                 .Where(x => x.AssignedTo.Split(',').Contains(value) || search == null)
```

Or redesign
your database to use related tables rather than storing a comma-delimited list of strings...

Comment: There is an error when I try it {"Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[BudgetLib.BudgetProject]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BudgetLib.BudgetProject]'."}

Comment: @Denis `records` must be declared as an `IQueryable`, and the conversion to `IEnumerable` is breaking that contract. You can try using a new variable (`records2` would be the lazy name` to allow a different type, or no use `var` (explicitly use `IEnumerable<...>` when declaring the variable.

Comment: Thank you very much @D Stanley!

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a linq expression against database then Split function will throw an error. You can use expression below there.

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
records = records.Where(x => (',' + x.AssignedTo + ',').Contains(',' + value + ',')
}