# How to create a generic text file parser for any find of text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, text-parsing

Want to create a generic text file parser in c# for any find of text file.Actually i have 4 application all 4 getting input data from txt file format but text files are not homogeneous in nature.i have tried fixedwithdelemition.

```
private static DataTable FixedWidthDiliminatedTxtRead()
{
    string[] fields;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<StringBuilder> lst = new List<StringBuilder>();
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    ArrayList aList;

    using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(testOCC))
    {
        tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth;
        tfp.SetFieldWidths(new int[12] { 2,25,8,12,13,5,6,3,10,11,10,24 });
        for (int col = 1; col < 13; ++col)
            dtable.Columns.Add("COL" + col);
        while (!tfp.EndOfData)
        {
            fields = tfp.ReadFields();
            aList = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
                aList.Add(fields[i] as string);
            if (dtable.Columns.Count == aList.Count)

            dtable.Rows.Add(aList.ToArray());


        }
    }
    return dtable;
}
```

but i feel its very rigid one and really varies application to application making it configgurable .any better way ..

```
tfp.SetFieldWidths(new int[12] { 2,25,8,12,13,5,6,3,10,11,10,24 });
```

File nature :
Its a report kind of file .
position of columns are very similar
row data of file id different .

I get this as a reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F

any other thoughts ?

Comment: Not my field, but I'm guessing if you're having 4 different txt formats you could have 4 different int arrays to feed into tfp.SetFieldWidths(). Maybe you should write a routine that finds out which of the 4 types of text you're dealing with, and then calls FixedWidthDiliminatedTxtRead passing an int[] parameter with the columns number and length already defined...

Comment: Instead of writing the code yourself, you could use a CSV parser component. For some options, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316649/csv-parsing.

Comment: Take a look at the FileHelpers library - http://www.filehelpers.com/. Even if you don't want to use it, it's a solid library that's been around for years and you can get some good ideas from it.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing different is the field widths, you could just try sending the field widths in as a parameter:

```
private static DataTable FixedWidthDiliminatedTxtRead(int[] fieldWidthArray)
{
    string[] fields;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<StringBuilder> lst = new List<StringBuilder>();
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    ArrayList aList;

    using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(testOCC))
    {
        tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth;
        tfp.SetFieldWidths(fieldWidthArray);
        for (int col = 1; col < 13; ++col)
            dtable.Columns.Add("COL" + col);
        while (!tfp.EndOfData)
        {
            fields = tfp.ReadFields();
            aList = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
                aList.Add(fields[i] as string);
            if (dtable.Columns.Count == aList.Count)

            dtable.Rows.Add(aList.ToArray());


        }
    }
    return dtable;
}
```

If you will have more logic to grab the data, you might want to consider defining an interface or abstract class for a `GenericTextParser` and create concrete implementations for each other file.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static DataTable FixedWidthTxtRead(string filename, int[] fieldWidths)
{
    string[] fields;
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    ArrayList aList;
    using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(filename))
    {
        tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth;
        tfp.SetFieldWidths(fieldWidths);
        for (int col = 1; col <= fieldWidths.length; ++col)
            dtable.Columns.Add("COL" + col);
        while (!tfp.EndOfData)
        {
            fields = tfp.ReadFields();
            aList = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
                aList.Add(fields[i] as string);
            if (dtable.Columns.Count == aList.Count) dtable.Rows.Add(aList.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return dtable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I made one of these last week.

I did not write it with the intentions of other people using it so I appologize in advance if its not documented well but I cleaned it up for you. ALSO I grabbed several segments of code from stack overflow so I am not the original author of several pieces of this.

The places you need to edit are the path and pathout and the seperators of text. 
char[] delimiters = new char[]

So it searches for part of a word and then grabs the whole word. I used a c# console application for this.

Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;

namespace UniqueListofStringFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"c:\Your Path\in.txt";
            string pathOut = @"c:\Your Path\out.txt";
            string data = "!";

            Console.WriteLine("Current Path In is set to: " + path);
            Console.WriteLine("Current Path Out is set to: " + pathOut);
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Input String to Search For:");
            Console.Read();
            string input = Console.ReadLine();            

            // Delete the file if it exists. 
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create the file. 
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
                {
                    Byte[] info =
                        new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");

                    // Add some information to the file.
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }
            }

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
            List<string> Spec = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                while (!file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string s = file.ReadLine();
                    if (s.Contains(input))
                    {                            
                        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\r', '\n', '\t', ')', '(', ',', '=', '"', '\'', '<', '>', '$', ' ', '@', '[', ']' };
                        string[] parts = s.Split(delimiters,
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        foreach (string word in parts)
                        {
                            if (word.Contains(input))
                            {                                   
                                if( word.IndexOf(input) == 0)
                                {
                                    Spec.Add(word);
                                }
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                }


                Spec.Sort();

                // Open the stream and read it back. 

                //while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine(s);
                //}
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in Spec) // Loop through all strings
            {
                builder.Append(s).Append(Environment.NewLine); // Append string to StringBuilder
            }
            string result = builder.ToString(); // Get string from StringBuilder


            Program a = new Program();

            data = a.uniqueness(result);

            int i = a.writeFile(data,pathOut);

        }

        public string uniqueness(string rawData )
        {
            if (rawData == "")
            {
                return "Empty Data Set";
            }

            List<string> dataVar = new List<string>();  
            List<string> holdData = new List<string>();

            bool testBool = false;
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(rawData))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {    

                    foreach (string s in holdData)
                    {
                        if (line == s)
                        {
                            testBool = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (testBool == false)
                    {
                        holdData.Add(line);
                    }
                    testBool = false;
                    // Do something with the line
                }
            }    

            int i = 0;
            string dataOut = "";
            foreach (string s in holdData)
            {                   
                dataOut += s + "\r\n";
                i++;
            }

            // Write the string to a file.
            return dataOut;
        }

        public int writeFile(string dataOut, string pathOut)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathOut);
                file.WriteLine(dataOut);

                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dataOut += ex.ToString();
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:
I built a factory for the type of processor needed (based on file type/format), which abstracted the file reader.
I then built a collection object that contained a set of triggers for each field I was interested in (also contained the property name for which this field is destined).  This settings collection is loaded in via an XML configuration file, so all I need to change are the settings, and the base parsing process can react to how the settings are configured.  Finally I built a reflection wrapper wherein once a field is parsed, the corresponding property on the model object is set.
As the file flowed through, the triggers for each setting evaluated each lines value. When it found what it was set to find (via pattern matching, or column length values) it fired and event that bubbled up and set a property on the model object.  I can show some pseudo code if you're interested.  It needs some work for efficiency's sake, but I like the concept.